# Is the response time from Cloud Foundry RTR Logs in milliseconds or seconds?

Tags: logging, cloud-foundry

I'm currently analyzing the RTR Logs of a Cloud Foundry application. I was not able to find the time formate for the response_time value in any documentation. Has somebody further information regarding that topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time is given in milliseconds. There is documentation on the [access log format](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/adminguide/troubleshooting-router-error-responses.html#access-logs), which does not contain the unit. However, the documentation on the [component metrics](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/running/all_metrics.html#routing) state, that the value is in milliseconds.